# Minimizing duplicate routes index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, url-routing

I am trying to build a REST API with express router, which contains of nested sub routes. I have mounted these sub routes in my `index.js` file.

I have defined it as follows:

```
// Mounted routes
app.use('/api/v1/Project', new ProjectRouter().routes);
app.use('/api/v1/Project/:projectId/Context', new ContextRouter().routes);
app.use('/api/v1/Project/:projectId/Context/:contextId/Question', new QuestionRouter().routes);
app.use('/api/v1/Project/:projectId/Context/:contextId/Question/:questionId/Answer', new AnswerRouter().routes);
```

I want to arrange my routes revolved around the functionality and being more complaint towards REST standards.

**In the case the route prefix `/api/v1/Project/` is being repeated over and over again.**

Is there some best practice to minimize the redundant routes by prefixing?

Comment: This may be a little ancillary to what you are saying, but it is a common practice to limit the depth of your routes. https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/urls.html For instance, you most likely dont need project and context in the url to modify a question's anwser.

Answer (score 1):

This is where the Express Router class comes in.  You could define a router for ‘api/v1/Project’, mount that router to you main app, and then add the individual routes to the router.

Answer (score -1):

The main idea is you can define routes in each controller (no matter how). For hide the base route, you can use a base class with a method addRoute and a property baseRoute or just use a simple variable for base route.

With Ecma6 will look something like this:

in projects.controller.js

```
require('base.controller.js')
class ProjectsController extends BaseController {
  constructor(app){
    super(app, "/api/v1/Project");
    this.addRoute("/", "get", this.getAll);
    this.addRoute("/:id", "get", this.getOne)
  }
  getAll(){}
  getOne(){}
}
module.exports = ProjectsController;
```

in 'base.controller.js':

```
class BaseController {
  constructor(app, baseRoute){
    this.baseRoute = baseRoute;
    this.app = app
  }
  addRoute(route, method, callback){
    const url = this.baseRoute + route;
    console.log('controllerRoute', url, method);
    this.app[method](url, callback.bind(this));
 }
}
module.exports=BaseController;
```

and in index.js (or app/server.js), for each controller:

```
require("./projects.controller.")(app);
```

The simplest way:

```
let baseRoute = "/api/v1/Project";
app.use(baseRoute + "/", new ProjectRouter().routes);
app.use(baseRoute + '/:projectId/Context', new ContextRouter().routes);
```

Comment: Kunal isn't using TypeScript, and this setup has multiple issues. 1. Method isn't passed to `addRoute`. 2. No `super()` call. 3. No nice way to specify another controller is under `/api/v1/Project`. 4. Routes are currently looking like `/api/api/...`

Comment: Yes you are right. I corrected the mistakes. What do you mean by 3. ?

Comment: You mean is not ok to define a base class for controller?

Comment: About typescript: Ecma6 is very similar with Typescript (except types), so why is this a problem?